# Draw images with warped triangles on a web server

Tags: image-manipulation, cgi, imagemagick

#### The scenario

The Flash front end of my current project produces images that a web server needs to combine into a video. Both frame-rate and frame-resolution are sizeable enough that sending an image sequence to the back end is not feasible (in both time and client bandwidth). Instead, we're trying to recreate the image drawing on the back end as well.

#### Correct and slow, or incorrect and fast

The problem is that this involves quite a bit of drawing textured triangles, and two solutions we found in Python ([here](http://www.janeriksolem.net/2009/06/piecewise-affine-warping-using-scipy.html) and [there](https://github.com/TimSC/image-piecewise-affine)) are so inefficient, that the drawing takes about 60 seconds per frame, resulting in a whopping 7,5 hours of processing time for a 30 second clip. Unacceptable.

When using a PHP-module to send commands to ImageMagick for image manipulation, the whole process is super fast (tenths of a second per frame), but [ImageMagick seems to be unable to draw triangles](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/operators/distort.php) the way we do it in the front end, so the final results do not match. Unacceptable.

What I'm asking here, is if there's someone who would know a way to solve this issue, by any means necessary that would run on a web server.

#### Warping an image

Let me explain the process of the front end:

1. Perform a Delaunay calculation on points in an image to get an evenly distributed mesh of triangles.
2. Offset the points/vertices in the mesh, distorting or warping the image.
3. Draw the warped triangles on a new bitmap.

[image: Original image on the left, warped image on the right]

We can send the results (coordinates) of steps 1 and 2 to the back end, to then draw the warped triangles and save it to an image on disk (or append as a frame to the video). But that last step is what I need help with.

#### The Question

Is there an alternative to ImageMagick that can draw triangles in a bitmap? Is there some other library, like a C library, that would allow us to do this? Or could we achieve this effect more easily by switching back end technologies, like Ruby? (.Net and Java are, unfortunately, not really options right now)

Many thanks. EP.

*P.S. I'd appreciate re-tagging efforts, I don't quite know what labels to put on this question. Thanks!*

Comment: could this not be done client side via html 5 canvas?

Comment: True, the client side portion could be done on a canvas, but getting 450 frames to the server is the issue. That's why the images need to be drawn server side.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand, quite what you are trying to do. Could you describe what this system does from client end to server? or suppose to do?

Comment: The server will receive A) a source image, B) a list of UV-points, C) a list of UV-indices that compose the triangle mesh. Lastly, D) is a list of points that differ from the original UV-positions, which when drawn correctly results in a warped image/frame.  

There will be many of these lists eventually, one for each frame, but just getting one image drawn by the server would be enough to get going.

Comment: In short, @Darknight, I want the server to draw an image like the right chair in my example image.

Comment: perhaps use blender, using python you can create a simple plane, point the camera at a normal, then script the points move each frame, render directly as a video file.

Comment: at least that's how I would tackle this. I think blender can even run headless (think render-farm), thus perfect for a server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17450/discussion-between-epologee-and-darknight)

Comment: No solution, but a suggestion: If you would highlight the modified triangles in the right image, it would be clear at first sight what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opencv is a c library that supports many types of image warping and compositing.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for posting. We indeed just solved this issue last week by writing our own app in C, using OpenCV. It renders the image frames at 480p resolution in under 500msecs, which is sufficient for our cause.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same technology on both sides will get you the most consistent results and the easiest time keeping algorithms in sync. If you use canvas, you could also use nodecanvas with node.js on the server to do image generation server-side the same way.  (don't have to switch everything over. You could just run a warping server process)

https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas